# <meta> not working when initial-scale is changed

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, meta-tags

By default, in the index.html file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

I changed it to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2" />
```

Nothing happened.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: How to get it to also work on the browser desktop?

Answer (score 1):

meta viewport is only supported by mobile browsers.

To achieve the same effect on a desktop browser, you can use the [`zoom` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom).

```css
body{
  zoom: 200%;
}
```

```html
Hello World!
```

Comment: I have a top bar was is stickied. But when zoom is set, it is no longer stickied. How can I have it not affect the sticky components?